# Apache2 - Can not open error log file

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, logging, log-files

I'm installing Apache2 on Debian Wheezy.

After the file's mod ***/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl***, I wrote **apache2** for running the service. 
Sadly, the Linux shell backs this string:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(2)No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /etc/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log.
Unable to open logs
```

How I resolve this problem?

Comment: Access using root user and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if http is already running because it shows 'Address already in use message'

Check

```
ps -ef | grep http
```

Kill PIDs of http if listed

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Now try to start http service.

Comment: Error when i write the kill command: "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'"

Comment: @francesco-guarneri You should use kill command without < >.
It should be 
kill -9 2345
Not
kill -9 <2345>
I hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

`Address already in use` is your clue.  Try this as root:

```
# netstat -anp | grep :443 | grep LISTEN
```

The output will look something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 11.22.33.44:443         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2511/apache2
```

The last column gives you the PID and name of the process listening on port 443.  You'll have to get rid of that process before Apache will be able to bind to the port.

Comment: I haven't an output when I write these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your logfile directives look like this:

```
    ErrorLog "/etc/apache2/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/etc/apache2/logs/access_log"
```